# Why does the GetUsersInRoleAsync-method only works in .cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a webapplication (.NET Core with Razor Pages, not mvc and indivudual user accounts) where I'd need to display users with it's corresponding roles.

Can anyone explain me what the difference is between the following code blocks:

### Not working using Users.cshtml.cs

```
public class UsersModel : PageModel
{
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public IList<ApplicationUser> admins { get; set; }

    public UsersModel(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async void OnGet()
    {
        admins = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admins").Result;
    }
 }
```

It crashes and produces an error while loading the page.

### Working using Users.cshtml

```
@page
@model UsersModel
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager
@{
 var admins = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admins").Result;
}

@foreach(var user in @Model.admins)
{
    <h3>@user</h3>
}
```

So, there is no syntax error in the first (not working) codeblock. When I am running the code I am receiving the `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`' **Before marking this post as duplicate, I am not looking for an answer about fixing this specific error.**

I'd like to know if anyone can tell me the difference between the .cshtml-version and .cs-version? I'd like to use the .cshtml.cs-version since it's clearer.

#### edit 1

```
// not this
public UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

// but this
var _userManager serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Comment: Please check the tags twice when posting...

Comment: Edited my post. Thanks for noticing. Could you tell me what's the difference?

Comment: [tag:c] vs [tag:c#]

Comment: 1st case you are creating a private object and not assigning it anything hence null hence error, 2nd case you are injecting it which gets its value and hence works

Comment: `async void` - I'll do some work but you're have no way to determine *when I'm done*. If you're relying on `OnGet` to make sure that `admins` has been assigned a value, why are you using a method where you explicitly have no means to determine when it's finished?

Comment: I am not that familiar with razor pages yet, so I don't quite understand your question. The reason for using OnGet would be, I'd like to keep my .cshtml as clean as possible and using server side code in the .cs-file wherever I can

Comment: @M.Douglas what he is referring to is async code typically returns a `Task` or `Task<T>` so the caller can `await` it in the case they need to wait for it to finish before moving on. the return type of OnGet should be `Task`, not `void` in this case. Using void is discouraged unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

`_userManager` is null in your cs version because you are not injecting it as a dependency.

in the razor version you have specified for that object to be provided with @inject.

you will need to add a constructor to your cs version and inject the _userManager dependency however the framework you are using does it.

typically it would look something like this:

```
private readonly IUserManager<IApplicationUser> _userManager;

public UsersModel(
    IUserManager<IApplicationUser> userManager) {
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

The injected dependencies typically work at the interface level, not the concrete type level. this will avoid lots of code refactoring later if you ever have to change the concrete implementation of something.

Comment: Okj, I think I understand your point. But it's injecting the _userManager-dependency in my .cshtml file. I'd like to use it in my .cs-file. Can I inject/reference it as well in my .cs file? Haven't done much before with razor pages.

Comment: yes, you can inject the dependency in the cs file. what dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: Like I said in my first post, .NET Core v2 web application (not mvc) with Razor Pages

Comment: that is the web framework, you can pick a variety of dependency injection frameworks to use with it. i'll assume you are using the default provided implementation.